# cursor is not from the beginning in my text box? why so?

Tags: html

i have a text area called bio graphy in this form.it is not in the beginning it comes in the middle of the text box. whats wrong in my code?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> form </title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form action="formed.php" method="POST">

Bio-grpahy<input type="text" autofocus="true" value ="" rows="3" maxlength="1000"     style="width:250;height:150;"</input> </br> </br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>  
<input type="reset" value="reset"/> </br> </br>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Cursor is in at the start position not middle. See here http://jsfiddle.net/10d1qwou/

Answer (score 1):

For your biography field, you probably want to use a `textarea` element instead of `input`. `rows` is not a valid attribute for the HTML `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use **textarea** da :P not to use center tag for input tag da its for div da